# Why wont my i5 fit my MSI model P67A-S40?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

The quad i5 I bought for my new desktop is an i5-4670K LGA1150

My motherboard is a MSI P67A-S40 Core i7 socket 1155 Motherboard w/ Intel P67 Express Chipset USB 3

Does the fact that Core i7 is listed specify that it MUST take an i7 despite the 1155 being the same? As I understand motherboards no one board is limited to one specific type of CPU in such a way.  Furthermore the MSI website doesn't list this board for its support...

Why won't my CPU fit? Is this board bogus?

To specify *won't fit*, when I line up the notches on my CPU with the pegs that fit in the notches, the CPU hangs off the dock by about 1\16 of an inch.

Comment: Any ix-3xxx Ivybridge processor will fit your motherboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Most) Haswell processors are built for Socket 115**0**. It is *not compatible* with Socket 115**5** (Sandy/Ivy Bridge).

Comment: You have no idea how retarded I feel right now, how could I have missed that!?

Comment: The names are quite similar, after all. There's also a i3-3220 and a i5-3320 – subject to some confusion in much the same way.